# Function weird output while pushing obj to arr

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have the following function

```
function toDays(startDateString, endDateString) {

  const startDate = moment(startDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY');
  const endDate = moment(endDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY');

  const dates = [];

  while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'day')) {
    const currentDay = startDate.format('dddd');
    dates[currentDay].push({start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});
    startDate.add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dates;
}

const result = toDays('Monday Dec 24 2018', 'Friday Dec 28 2018');
console.log(result);
```

It returns an error when i use the `dates[currentDay].push({start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});`
 , what I am trying to achieve is to push those keys on a currentDay, so like pushing an object up an array. The error is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

However, if I use
`dates[currentDay] = {start:'9:00', end:'18:00'};`
 it works just fine, but I'm not sure if it's the right way. Any ideeas?

Comment: I think you want this `dates.push({currentDay: currentDay, start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});` instead of this `dates[currentDay].push({start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dates` array does not have an item with index `currentDay`.
Try this to see it for yourself:

```
const currentDay = startDate.format('dddd');
var obj = dates[currentDay];
console.log(obj);
obj.push({start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});
startDate.add(1, 'days');
```

Place this code inside the `while()` statement. It will output on the console `undefined`.

To solve this problem test if `currentDay` is in `dates` or populate `dates` appropriately, like this:

```
if (typeof dates[currentDay] === "undefined") // test
{
  // does not exist, yet: initialize
  dates[currentDay] = [];
}

// ...
dates[currentDay].push(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check first if dates[currentDay] exists. If not do dates[currentDay] = [] before push.

dates[currentDay] = {start:'9:00', end:'18:00'} is working because it is assigning an object directly at that location, which was initially undefined.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying t push on object to somethig that doesn't exist yet. The method you proposed:

```
dates[currentDay] = {start: '9:00', end: '18:00'}
```

Is the most corect way of doing this, although you really should not be modifying a constant variable or your code will break. To prevent this from becoming an isue, use:

```
var dates = [];
```

instead of:

```
const dates = [];
```